# Google Hangouts will not connect Errors: 212, 213, 214

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I have been doing some research but I have been coming across many different answers that do not seem to be working.

I have been told that creating a new group will work but the problem for me is that it will not allow me to even open Google Hangouts.  I have Google Chrome extension and the Google format but I cannot use either one.

The app is used for personal matters and the Chrome tab is used for school work and studying.

I do not understand computers as extensively as everyone on this site and would like to fix Google Hangouts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to clear the cache and to sign in and out a few times while restarting the browser.
Sometimes the problem resolves itself after some tries and even reboots.

If this doesn't resolve itself after a few tries and a day or two, then your account
may be corrupted. Try creating a new account, and if it works then save your data,
such as bookmarks, and move over to that account.

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question.

Comment: @DavidPostill: Not if it fixes the problem, it isn't.

Comment: thank you this work very well and only took me about three minutes.